# How to download data from Google Scholar?

Tags: database, search, download, google-scholar

I want to do some analysis on the keywords and the titles of papers from a specific period of time and with particular keywords used. Let's say I want to download all the papers published between 2010 and 2020 that contain the keywords `soccer` and `economics` in Google Scholar. I don't want to download all the papers, just their titles, authors, date, journals - basically info about them. Is there a way to download this data from the search in Google Search? Do I need to use some external software or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for this: https://serpapi.com/google-scholar-api? A simple Google search will find the result.

Comment: Well, maybe that works. But I'm not really comfortable working with API's. I was wondering if there is a software that outputs a sheet or maybe an R package/Python library

Comment: @ArturVidaurredeAlmeida seems like [`scholarly`](https://github.com/scholarly-python-package/scholarly) might fit your needs.